# Loading a groovy class in ant build.xml and storing return value in ant property?

Tags: ant, groovy

I have folder **test** containing:

```
test
 -> groovy
     -> MyClass.groovy
 -> build.xml
```

The file **MyClass.groovy** contains:

```
class MyClass {
  void firstMethod(int i) {
    println i
  }

  String secondMethod(String txt) {
    return txt + "added text"
  }

  static void main(String[] args) {

  }
}
```

In my **build.xml** file I have (based on http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/The+groovy+Ant+Task):

```
<target name="run-groovy-script-test">
    <groovy src="groovy/MyClass.groovy">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="groovy"/>
      </classpath>
        def aClass = new MyClass()
        aClass.secondMethod("asd")
    </groovy>
</target>
```

Running the above gives:

```
 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: MyClass.secondMethod() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [some-text]
```

**Solution**: Remove the src attribute - see below comments.

I know that I can specify a **main** method in the .groovy file which will automatically be executed using the above. But it could be nice to control which methods should be called directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Declare a property in your ant.xml. 

<property name="myproperty" value=""/>

<groovy>
    //This will instantiate
    def aClass = new MyClass()

    //This will store the return value in the ant property
    properties["myproperty"] = aClass.secondMethods()
</groovy>
```

Comment: but I need to pass an argument to the secondMethod(String txt) method and it gives an error. See the edited post.

Comment: The snippet is right. Looks like the problem is with src="groovy/MyClass.groovy". Try removing the src attribute as in the posted answer. But for that to work, you need to have MyClass on your classpath. Check this:http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/The+groovy+Ant+Task

Comment: yes removing the src attribute fixed the problem. After adding the classpath tag it now works

Comment: How are you adding the classpath tag? When I'm adding it, I'm still getting the same error as yours.

Answer (score 0):

*"But it could be nice to control which methods should be called directly."*

@u123:  I'm no groovy expert and last year I didn't find an obvious solution to address that. So at the time I made a tiny tool out of frustration, to solve my issues with the ant groovy task:

[Feniseca](http://code.google.com/p/blu-strglr-grovecell/).

It's open source and I just updated the doc, but note that I tested Feniseca only against POSIX environments. Hoping this can help anyway!